# images stacked(overlapped) when leaving the window tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

I have images that move cross the window(in 2 lines), when I leave the page tab,then going back to it all of the images are stacked on each other.
JS code(credits to [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00))

```
function startMoving(img) {

        var img$ = $(img);
        var imgWidth = img$.width();
        var screenWidth = $(window).width();
        var amount = screenWidth - parseInt(img$.css("left"), 10);
        // if already past right edge, reset to 
        // just left of left edge
        if (amount <=0 ) {
            img$.css("left", -imgWidth);
            amount = screenWidth + imgWidth;
        }
        var moveRate = 300;   // pixels per second to move
        var time = amount * 1000 / moveRate;
        img$.stop(true)
        .animate({
            left: "+=" + amount
        }, time, "linear", function() {
            // when animation finishes, start over
            startMoving(this);
        })

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // readjust if window changes size
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $(".thumbnails").each(function() {

            startMoving(this);
        });
    });
});
```

html code:

```
   <div id="thumbnails_wrapper">
          <img src="http://d17g46tfi0dv3u.cloudfront.net/8294/148294_e492b405eed74bc3ba9f994affac423c.jpg" onload="startMoving(this)" style="top:0px;left:100px" class="thumbnails"/>
          <img src="http://d17g46tfi0dv3u.cloudfront.net/8294/148294_e492b405eed74bc3ba9f994affac423c.jpg" onload="startMoving(this)" style="top:0px;left:200px"
        class="thumbnails"/>
          <img src="http://d17g46tfi0dv3u.cloudfront.net/8294/148294_e492b405eed74bc3ba9f994affac423c.jpg" onload="startMoving(this)" style="top:0px;left:300px"
        class="thumbnails"/>
          <img src="http://d17g46tfi0dv3u.cloudfront.net/8294/148294_e492b405eed74bc3ba9f994affac423c.jpg" onload="startMoving(this)" style="top:100px;left:100px" class="thumbnails"/>
          <img src="http://d17g46tfi0dv3u.cloudfront.net/8294/148294_e492b405eed74bc3ba9f994affac423c.jpg" onload="startMoving(this)" style="top:100px;left:200px" class="thumbnails"/>
          <img src="http://d17g46tfi0dv3u.cloudfront.net/8294/148294_e492b405eed74bc3ba9f994affac423c.jpg" onload="startMoving(this)" style="top:100px;left:300px" class="thumbnails"/>

    </div>
```

CSS code:

```
#thumbnails_wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;

    height:147px;
background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.4);

}
.thumbnails{
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid white;

}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ScTMP/

Answer (score 1):

Well, you already know that your application is going haywire. The problem is your function that runs infinitely and is out of your control (i.e., when the visitor opens a new tab and moves away from the active window).

You have to be very careful with functions that call themselves. Creating infinite loops can eat up CPU resources and crash the visitor's browser.

But you have a way to get control of  your animation using JavaScript's window object. Let's say you've opened four tabs in your browser. The browser creates one window object for each those tabs. You can use the window object's onblur and onfocus event handlers to find out what the visitor is doing at the browser level:

```
goMoving();
window.onblur = stopMoving;
window.onfocus = goMoving;

var int;

function goMoving() {
    int = setInterval(function() {
        moveTheBoxes();            
    }, 400); //TODO (AzizAG): Rework the timer function
}

function stopMoving() {
    window.clearInterval(int);
}

function startMoving(img) {
    /* Animation */
}
```

The **key to success** are the lines 2-3. The goMoving function is your **new** way to call moveTheBoxes again and again. Therefore, change your animation:

```
.animate({
    left: "+=" + amount
}, time, "linear");
```

Comment: What do you mean by `reworking` the timer function?(And why?)

Comment: What I'm about to say is: Put the code above and your algorithm together so that it arrives at a conclusion that fulfills your requirements. The key to the mystery are the window object's onblur and onfocus event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that I've noticed recently in Chrome and Firefox. Animations seem to do funky things when you go to another tab and come back. I haven't found a good solution yet, but you're not alone.